# How do prevent page reload/refresh from submitting ajax called form and get the texts and uploaded file/image?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I want to call forms and upload image with some texts. But i dont want submitting refresh the page. How can i do that? Thank you very much...

[image: Form called with ajax]

When i click to Bring Form button a form comes and when i clicked to submit button page refreshing and form disapears. Like this...

[image: when clicked to Submit]
Form disapears. I dont want this. How to do that? Here codes...

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>TEXT & FILE UPS</title>
</head>
<body>

    <button onclick="bring_form();" >Bring Form</button>

    <span id="form_field"></span>

    <script src="assets/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>   
    <script src="assets/js/custom.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

custom.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$("#form_1_0").on('submit',(function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault();

    var formData = new FormData(this);

    var action = "test";

    formData.append('action', action);

    $.ajax({
        url: "actions.php",
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            alert(data);
        },
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });

    return false;
}));

});



function bring_form(){
var action = "bring_form";  
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "actions.php", 
    beforeSend: function () {
    },
    data: {action: action},
    success: function(msg)
    {           
        var msg = msg.trim();

        $("#form_field").html(msg);

    }
});
}
```

actions.php

```
<?php

if(!empty($_POST)){

    $action = $_POST["action"];

    if($action == "bring_form"){

        echo '<form id="form_1_0" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
                <input type="text" name="txt_1" value="Bob" />
                <input type="text" name="txt_2" value="James" />
                <input type="text" name="txt_3" value="Smith" />
                <input name="image" type="file" />
                <button >Submit</button>
            </form>';

    }elseif($action == "test"){

        print_r($_POST);
        print_r($_FILES);

    }

}

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to delegate the submit handler to an element that actually exists at the time you call it since the form doesn't exist

Try changing:

```
$("#form_1_0").on('submit',(function(e){
```

To

```
$(document).on('submit',"#form_1_0",function(e){
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. Well, what can i do if forms are dynamic? Like #form_1_0, #form_1_1, #form_1_2?

Comment: Use a common class for them and use that class as the delegation target